# how to pass parameter in action tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to pass the `res` variable as a form action. Is this possible with HTML?

```
 <script>
    var name =$("#name").val();
    var file =$("#file").val();
    var res= localhost:8080 + "/test/reg?&name="+name+"&file=" +file  ;
    </script>
    <form action="res" id ="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    Upload:<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/> 
    </form>

document.forms["form"].submit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the action property before submitting it:

```
var form = document.forms["form"];
form.action = res;
form.submit();
```

If the user can submit this form manually then you can use the `onsubmit` event:

```
form.onsubmit = function(){
    this.action = res;
};
```